# RAWINPUT.Keyboard: How to detect arrow keys when NUMLOCK=ON?

Tags: c++, winapi, raw-input

When **NUMLOCK=ON** then

Key **ARROW_UP** pressed:

```
data.keyboard.MakeCode = 42;
data.keyboard.VKey = 255;
data.keyboard.Flags = 2;
data.keyboard.Message = 256 (WM_KEYDOWN)
```

Key **ARROW_DOWN** pressed:

```
data.keyboard.MakeCode = 42;
data.keyboard.VKey = 255;
data.keyboard.Flags = 2;
data.keyboard.Message = 256 (WM_KEYDOWN)
```

Key **ARROW_LEFT** pressed:

```
data.keyboard.MakeCode = 42;
data.keyboard.VKey = 255;
data.keyboard.Flags = 2;
data.keyboard.Message = 256 (WM_KEYDOWN)
```

Key **ARROW_RIGHT** pressed:

```
data.keyboard.MakeCode = 42;
data.keyboard.VKey = 255;
data.keyboard.Flags = 2;
data.keyboard.Message = 256 (WM_KEYDOWN)
```

**How to detect arrow keys when NUMLOCK=ON?**

- When **NUMLOCK=OFF** then all working well;
- DirectInput (from DirectX 8.0) works well in both cases;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flag: RIDEV_NOLEGACY and filter messages where VKey == 255